# How do i get another window to recognize alt+ f4 key press

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to send alt + f4 combination from my c++ application to another window. I can get it to work for ctrl + c but when i try to close the application by sending the code below which is alt + f4 it isn't doing what i expect it to do. What is the correct combination for alt + f4?

```
INPUT ip;

ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

ip.ki.wVk = VK_MENU; 
   ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
   SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

   ip.ki.wVk = VK_F4; 
   ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
   SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

   ip.ki.wVk = VK_MENU;
   ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
   SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

   ip.ki.wVk = VK_F4;
   ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
   SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Comment: SendMessage() + WM_CLOSE seems a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: SendMessage works. I was wondering what is wrong with my approach why isn't it working?

Comment: That looks okay. Make sure you have the foreground window. The input has to be sent as one array, not one by one.